# Determine the BJT working zones

Tags: bjt, homework

I have the following circuit 
[image]

I have to determine the zones where the BJT transistor is working according to the input voltage (which as you can see is a triangular wave with 4V amplitude). Now here's the thing: I know that if ui is negative that the BJT is on the open-circuit zone. ´
The problem comes when we have ui positive. We know for sure that emmiter-base junction is direct biased. The collector-base junction can however be direct or inverse biased. Do you have any idea how can I determine the values of ui?

Answer (score 1):

If Beta of the BJT is assumed to be 100 here, then the transistor will work in active region when ui = positive; otherwise in cut-off region. CB is reverse biased of course, just apply KVL through that outer most loop and find VCB (You will get a positive value).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum gain for a Common_emitter bipolar one-transistor amplifier is

VDD/0.026 or VDD * 39 (at room temperature).

You have 20 * 39 or nearly gain of 800.

Your maximum Vinput peakpeak will be small (at least without the 100K ohm).
Yet you want to inject 4 volts.

I suggest you bias the transistor at 0.6v or 0.7v, to place Vcollector at +10 volts. And superimpose +-10milliVolts triangle atop that bias.